# How to close LocationSettingsRequest dialog when we enable location from top status bar?

Tags: android, gps, location, android-statusbar

> This is my sample code for prompting the user for to enable GPS location.

```
 private void showLocationSettingsRequest(Context context) {
    try {
        /* Initiate Google API Client  */
        GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(SPPlaysetScanActivity.this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        googleApiClient.connect();

        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(10000 / 2);

        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                final Status status = result.getStatus();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            status.startResolutionForResult(SPActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "showLocationSettingsRequest :PendingIntent unable to execute request.");
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Log.d(TAG, "showLocationSettingsRequest :Location settings are inadequate,
                        // and cannot be fixed here. Dialog not created.");
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "showLocationSettingsRequest EX:" + e.toString());
    }
}
```

> If we disable location from status bar setting we are able to get the location settings dialog but when we turn on location (from the top status bar) but still the location dialog appears. I need to dismiss dialog when the location is turned on from status bar settings.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible on your code's side.
Calling:

```
status.startResolutionForResult(SPActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
```

You are opening separate `Activity` (from Google Play Services library). This code should be intelligent enough register `BroadcastReceiver` for location change and then return result to your `Activity` if GPS has been enabled.

As you can't change this code I guess what you need to do is write a change request on Google Issue tracker site: https://source.android.com/setup/report-bugs

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. That dialog is not part of your app. It's part of the android system, which does not offer this capability sadly.

However, if you think that your users, when prompted to enable location, can do that from the status bar, you can show your own dialog before this system dialog. That way, you'll have control over that dialog. Pressing ok on your dialog will take you to that system dialog. If the user were to turn the location on from the status bar, it is likely that they will do it during your own dialog. You can then hide it and never show the system dialog. Otherwise you can move forward and show it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if my answer suitable for you, just realize that user may enable location service from status bar, thank for your question makes me thinks more...

what I used for location service is like this:

```
private void checkLocationService(){
    boolean gpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    boolean networkEnable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if (!gpsEnabled && !networkEnable) {
        Log.e(TAG, "gps service not available");
        /*show dialog*/
        if (builder == null){
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Enable", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent settingLocation = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivityForResult(settingLocation, 101);
                }
            });
            builder.setMessage("Please enable location service!");
            alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "cancel tapped");
                    checkLocationService();
                }
            });
        }
        alertDialog.show();

    }
    else {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }
}
```

then wait from activity result to validate again

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    //Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(requestCode) + "|" + String.valueOf(resultCode));
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 101){
        boolean gpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        boolean networkEnable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (gpsEnabled || networkEnable){
            if (mMap != null){
                if (mapFragment.getView() != null){
                    View myLocationBtn = ((View) mapFragment.getView()
                            .findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).getParent())
                            .findViewById(Integer.parseInt("2"));
                    myLocationBtn.setClickable(true);
                    myLocationBtn.performClick();
                    //myLocationBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    /*if (myLocationBtn instanceof ImageView){
                        myLocationBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ic_launchers);
                    }*/

                    Log.e(TAG, "locationButton.performClick()");
                }

            }
        }
        else {
            checkLocationService();
        }
    }

}
```

hope this fit your answer

Comment: I am not navigating the user to settings screen just showing LocationSettingsRequest.Builder dialog. So this answer willn't help for me.